# Sticky button ionic at bottom of screen

Tags: ionic2, ionic3, sticky

I am making an Android app with ionic and I want to know how to make a sticky button that will always appear at the bottom of the screen when the user scrolls down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the **[footer](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/toolbar/Footer/)** component:

> Footer is a root component of a page that sits at the bottom of the
>   page. Footer can be a wrapper for ion-toolbar to make sure the content
>   area is sized correctly.

```
<ion-content></ion-content>

<ion-footer>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <button ion-button text-only>Your Button</button>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

Since the `ion-footer` is placed **outside** of the `ion-content`, the footer will always be shown, even if the page has a lot of content and the user is at the top of the page.

---

### [StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/footer-with-button)

---

Comment: I need the component to be always on the bottom of the screen while the user scrolls down. The component  must always be visible while the user scrolls down. The footer will only remain at the bottom of the screen and will not be visible if the user is at the top of long screen.

Comment: @Manos that's not correct; the footer **will always be shown** at the bottom of the page, even if the user is at the top of the page

Comment: Yes it always be at the bottom but I do not think it will be visible if the user is at the top of a long screen. I think I need to add some css to make it STICKY. Ex. position:fixed; bottom:0;

Comment: I will try and see. Thank you for your support.

Comment: @Manos I've added a StackBlitz demo to the answer so you can see how the footer works in Ionic :)

Comment: I added the css properties ion-footer{position:fixed;bottom:0;} and made it STICKY. Thank you again.

Comment: But it should work without it... Did you take a look at the StackBlitz demo link? Please notice that the `ion-footer` is placed outside of the `ion-content` element. That's how Ionic makes the footer to be sticky without the need of any additional style rule.

Comment: You are right about the footer. It is always shown even if the user is at the top of the screen. Once again thank you for your support

Comment: Glad to help @Manos :)